# URL Regex checking in Express, node

Tags: node.js, regex, api, express

I'm trying to validate the endpoints in the api-gateway.I have all the endpoints listed in database, the api-gateway will check for the endpoint is vaild or not, but its failing with url with params.

/user/:id

should accept -> /user/1(all numbers)

have to find a way to identify the endpoint as when the user id changes.

Comment: What do you mean by `dynamically identify url params`. The `/user/:id` will accepts url's like this `/user/hello`, `/user/qwe` as well. If you want to ensure that url is match only if `id` is `number` you need to specify right pattern like this `/user/:id(\d+)`. Here's detail explanation on how to use router https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: I just want url /user/:id to accept numbers, while this endpoint will be stored in db like -> user/1, user/2.

Comment: Then add something like https://github.com/hapijs/joi. That is the best optimal solution.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful